# Is there any error in my code, this is not working, Jquery Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to apply a `for` loop (or `do/while loop) but it is not working.

Without the `for` loop it works for one item but I want to implement the loop because I want multiple items in a single invoice.

```js
$(document).on('keyup', function() {
  for (var m = 1; m < 200; m++) {
    $("#item_name" + m).on('keyup', function() {
      var suppliercode = $(this).val();
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'sqty_dynamics.php',
        data: {
          item_name: suppliercode
        },
        success: function(data) {
          $("#order_item_squantity" + m).val(data);
        }
      });
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: whenever I see a question tagged as "php", I expect code for it. If there is no code or relevance, it should be removed, since it makes the question unclear and misleading to those such as I who follow that tag. So, relevance?

Comment: "not working" is not a clear problem statement. How is it not working?

Comment: Is the request not firing?  What does the console show?

Comment: On every `keyup` event of the document you're adding 199 new `keyup` events! O.o

Comment: There's several quite large flaws in your logic, but it's hard to correct this without seeing the relevant HTML and knowing exactly what you're attempting to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You are using two events one outside the loop and other is inside the loop. The outside loop it works and in the loop, it doesn't because it needs the `keyup` event for each iterate.

So you need to bind up inside event while firing out the event.

[See this click event](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/binding-click-event-in-a-loop)

Comment: Thanks Gufran Hassan, The link you share work for me after.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see in your code, you're putting your `for` loop inside of an event handler for the document's `keyup` handler. Is that what you meant to do?

Right now, that code says "when a keyup is detected on the whole document, add event listeners for more keyup events `m < 200` times on `m` item". That means every time the document gets `keyup`'d, the listeners for those individual items in the loop get re-added.

Certainly that's not what you were hoping to accomplish. Try just removing the `$(document).on(...)` part altogether and see what it does.

Comment: You are right. Thanks for helping me. i used $.each() to get the results.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Everybody for helping me. Mr Gufran Hasan share the link to find the answer. So, after some effort i found the answer.
This code works for me to getting the required results.

```
<script>
$(document).on('keyup',function(){
$(function() {
var dummy = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
$.each(dummy, function(i, v) { 
  $('#item_name' + i).keyup(function() {
              //alert(i);
  var suppliercode = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'sqty_dynamics.php',
      data:{item_name:suppliercode},
       success:function(data){
          $("#order_item_squantity"+ i).val(data);
        }
       });
     });
   });
 }); 
});
</script>
```